# Missing return statement while returning object or null

Tags: java, compiler-errors, return

I'm a student, this is an exercise and this is the goal of this method: 
 This method should return the first element of the Athlete array that has a name matching the
  name parameter. If there is no matching Athlete, return null.

For some reason, i'm getting this error,

```
TestAthletes.java:15: error: missing return statement
 }
```

This is my code:

```
public class TestAthletes{

   public static Athlete findAthleteByName(Athlete[] athletes, String name){
        for(int i=0; i<athletes.length; i++){
            if(name.equals(athletes[i].getName()))
                return athletes[i];
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: If the array is empty, you never return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `return null` statement should be outside the loop. Currently it will return `null` if the first value doesn't match.

```
public static Athlete findAthleteByName(Athlete[] athletes, String name){
    for(int i=0; i<athletes.length; i++){
        if(name.equals(athletes[i].getName()))
            return athletes[i];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Trace through what currently happens. You test `athletes[0]` the first time round the `for` loop. If it doesn't match, the `if` fails, it executes `else`, returning `null`.

Further, if the array is 0 length, nothing in the `for` loop will execute, hence it will never `return`.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is telling you that if by some chance you get to the end of the method, there's no return statement to return anything.

Not that your code is doing what you want it to do, but regardless, you should put a return statement, probably:

```
return null;
```

at the end of the method block.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a return statement after the `for` loop too because `athletes.length` can be 0 which means that the body of the `for` loop never gets executed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant the following

```
public class TestAthletes{

   public static Athlete findAthleteByName(Athlete[] athletes, String name){
        for(int i=0; i<athletes.length; i++){
            if(name.equals(athletes[i].getName()))
                return athletes[i];
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In your original code, if `athletes.length` is 0, then your loop never executes, and the code reaches the end of the function without returning anything.

Also, I presume you only want to return `null` if you didn't find a match at any iteration, so that's why I moved that return statement after the loop.